# MySQL workbench - self referring table and custom script

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I use MySQL 5.3.28 to create my database. One of the tables is referring itself, which is a big pain. Here is the originally created code:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhbpsychiatry`.`activity` (
`ActivityId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`NeedsRepeating` BINARY(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
`Prerequisition` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`ActivityName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`ActivityDescription` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ActivityId`) ,
 INDEX `Prerequisition` (`ActivityId` ASC) ,
 CONSTRAINT `Prerequisition`
 FOREIGN KEY (`ActivityId` ) 
 REFERENCES `dhbpsychiatry`.`activity` (`ActivityId` )

 ON DELETE NO ACTION
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Problem is of course with creating first row.

```
INSERT INTO `dhbpsychiatry`.`activity` (`ActivityId`, `Prerequisition`,
`ActivityName`) VALUES (1, 1, 'No prerequisition');
```

returns

```
  ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

Same if I try even simpler

```
INSERT INTO `dhbpsychiatry`.`activity` (`ActivityName`) 
VALUES ('No prerequisition');
```

I think I've tried all possibilities, making the FK nullable, not nullable, with or without default value...

After digging  a bit I've found something that works:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
Insert into activity (ActivityID, ActivityName) VALUES (0,'No prerequisition');
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

So I created a new SQL script in workbench with those lines.

So I have two questions here:

1. How I can add the first row without the script?

or if its impossible

2 How can I automatically add this script to be executed whenever I froward engineer the database?

Comment: "I think I've tried all possibilities, making the FK nullable, not nullable, with or without default value..." It sounds like you are just trying things at random intead of thinking logically about the problem!

Comment: After few hours of looking for solution you start to wonder is that the fault of your font size, lol ;) But seriously, changing the "null" and "default value" was looking like a step in right direction back then. Anyway, all solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your indexes and Foreign key definitions are confused. Main issue is that column `ActivityId` is referencing itself.

Try this:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dhbpsychiatry`.`activity` (
`ActivityId` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`NeedsRepeating` BINARY(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
`Prerequisition` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
`ActivityName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`ActivityDescription` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ActivityId`) ,
 INDEX `Prerequisition_idx` (`Prerequisition`) ,  --- changed the index name
                                                  --- and the indexed column

 CONSTRAINT `Prerequisition_fk`                   --- changed the constraint name

   FOREIGN KEY (`Prerequisition` )                --- main issue !! changed  
                                                  --- the referencing column
   REFERENCES `dhbpsychiatry`.`activity` (`ActivityId`)
     ON DELETE NO ACTION
     ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Comment: Thx, it seems to work! While I couldn't change the names of indexes without changing SQL statement (something I was trying to avoid), all I had to do is change the reference of foreign key. How could I miss that?

Comment: @Kris: You can change the index and constraint names, too, in Workbench.

Comment: Yes, you can but after running the forward engineering they get back to default names. Anyway, it wasn't necessary.